# Number of valid parenthesis

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

I have to find out the number of valid parenthesis.Parenthesis are of two type `[] ,()`. How many ways are there to construct a valid sequence using `X and Y number of [] ,() respectively`. For this problem we consider `([]) is invalid way` i.e () can't hold []. Is there any formula.

```
For Example X=1 and Y=1
[]()
()[]
[()]
```

The formula for $X=N,Y=0$ is $2^{N-1}$

Comment: Personally I did not understand the question. Is ((())) a valid sequence? You are missing definitions.

Comment: @moshe i assume it is

Comment: @cxzczxc why is the formula in exponential range are the parenthesis distinguishable and replaceable ?

Comment: The formula you give for when $Y=0$ is not correct. See [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) and [applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics).

Answer (score 1):

Say that there are $n$ pairs of square brackets and $m$ pairs of ordinary parentheses. There are $C_n$ valid strings of square brackets, where $C_n$ is the $n$-th Catalan number. Into any of the $2n+1$ gaps before the first square bracket, between adjacent square brackets, and after the last square bracket we can insert a valid string of parentheses, possibly empty, so long as the lengths of these $2n+1$ strings total $2m$. Every valid string $n$ pairs of square brackets and $m$ pairs of parentheses can be obtained uniquely in this way. If $$m=m_0+m_1+\ldots+m_{2n}$$ is a weak composition of $m$ into $2n+1$ parts, there are $\prod_{k=0}^{2n}C_{m_k}$ $(2n+1)$-tuples $\langle\sigma_0,\ldots,\sigma_{2n}\rangle$ of valid parenthesis strings such that $|\sigma_k|=2m_k$ for $k=0,\ldots,2n$, so if $s(n,m)$ is the number of valid strings of $n$ pairs of square brackets and $m$ pairs of parentheses, we must have

$$s(n,m)=C_n\left(\sum_{\substack{m_0,\ldots,m_{2n}\ge0\\m_0+\ldots+m_{2n}=m}}\prod_{k=0}^{2n}C_{m_k}\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

Catalan’s convolution formula, **Theorem** $\mathbf{2}$ in Alon Regev, [*A proof of Catalan’s Convolution formula*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0571), implies that

$$\sum_{\substack{m_0,\ldots,m_{2n}\ge0\\m_0+\ldots+m_{2n}=m}}\prod_{k=0}^{2n}C_{m_k}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+1+2m}\binom{2n+1+2m}m=\frac{2n+1}{2n+1+m}\binom{2n+2m}m\;,$$

so

$$s(n,m)=\frac{2n+1}{2n+1+m}\binom{2n+2m}mC_n\;.$$